# Github pages direct me to broken page

Tags: github, github-pages

I've tried to give my github page a custom domain, unsuccesfully i might add.
However now it wont won't as intended, like it did before i started messing around. [Github pages settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSXlF.png), looks like this.
But instead of redirecting me to https://malthegram.github.io/, it sends me to, http://www.malthegram.com/ which doesen't work.

Weird thing is, that it works just fine on Safari, but not on Chrome.

Any idea how I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: It's the DNS cache on Chrome, try enabling/disabling secure DNS in Chrome or switch the provider to force the cache to refresh

Comment: Hi @Martheen. Thank you for your input. Tried it with no succes. I do get this message on the wrong page: "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"

Comment: Edit: @Martheen fixed it by clearing cache and cookies directly in Chrome. Thank you for the idea